# In gnome w/ xmonad, how can I call a script when a monitor is plugged in OR when docking my laptop?

Tags: linux, gnome, acpi, xmonad

**Problem:**

I have an extra set of top and bottom gnome-panels for a second monitor.  When I undock my lenovo Thinkpad (T510), the extra top and bottom panels remain, so I have two on top and two on the bottom.  I am currently running a RHEL6/Fedora (x86_64) gnome (2.28.2) instance with xmonad (0.9.1-6.1.el6) set as the window manager, using the xmonad extensions to work within gnome.

**Tried:**

I've used acpi and found a code for docking and undocking, but when I try to utilize a script I found in [this blog post](http://blog.zoomeren.nl/2010/03/05/a-gnome-panel-for-each-connected-monitor/), it gets zero for the call to xrandr.  The script works when called on its own from the terminal.  I've tried calling a separate looping script in its own thread and it keeps getting zero for the value, long after the screen(s) update(s).

I have figured out how to have a script loop every X seconds and check for a file which is touched into existence in the event of the script getting a zero, then performing the necessary change, but I don't like that approach.

**Question:**

I'm hoping someone knows a place I can drop a call to the referenced script and have my panels come and go as I would expect without needing to initiate the script manually.

Thanks!

Update: I have added a bounty of 50 (max I can do) for an answer.

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess one of the problems listed below occures (or both):

1) looks like your xrandr snippet doesn't return proper values because the $DISPLAY environment variable is not set correctly. Acpi handler script normally runs as a user which is not the user running your current X session. That way xrandr just does not know which `$DISPLAY` to access.

2) if `$DISPLAY` is set correctly, the acpid user might still not be able to access your running xsession. You might check whether the script will work over acpi handler, if you execute `xhost +` as the user who is currently runging the current xsession with $DISPLAY specified in your script. This will disable access control for X. You can reenable it with `xhost -` again.

Check it, I hope it helps or will at least point you in which direction to dig.

Comment: Thanks for the answer jham.  I'll give your suggestions a shot when I'm at work next week (no dock here at home).

Comment: Was out sick today and probably won't have a chance to test out your theory for several days.